# Remote developing with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to set-up a remote C++ development with Eclipse Galileo, but just can't make it work.

Trying the NetBeans 6.8 worked almost out of box, as described in this article:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html

Is there any good article or tutorial, explaining how to setup such environment with Eclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyone successfully doing remote development here? (Successfully is the key word :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it a few months back but it didn't work for me either. Instead I use X-windows to open Eclipse from a remote linux box onto my Mac. This works well in office ( both machines are on a LAN in the same geographical location), but not from home. When working from home use emacs-gui to do the same things. Its not the perfect scene...but gets the work done.. It would be nice to see it work in eclipse some day :)

Comment: Hi.

I tried this, but it works too slow for me, even over LAN.

Had to switch to NetBeans, which gave me the additional value of dynamic code parsing and picking into "string" objects (which, amazingly, Eclipse can't do).

Regards.